# InsertAllOnSubmit (LINQ to SQL) generates duplicate entries in related tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables named Activity and ActivityType. There's a one-to-many relationship in between, with ActivityType as parent class and Activity as child class.

When I attempt to store newly created entities in the Activity table with relations to already existing ActivityType entities I end up with duplicate entries of those pre-existing ActivityType entities.

How can this be avoided?

This is how I create the new Activity entities with added relation to a pre-existing ActivityType entity:

```
var activities = (Session["Activities"] as List<D.Activity>);
if(activities == null)
    activities = new List<D.Activity>();

using (var dbContext = new D.DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var activityType = (from x in dbContext.ActivityTypes
                        where x.ClientID == this.Client.ClientID && x.ActivityTypeID == model.ActivityTypeID
                        select x).SingleOrDefault();

    var activity = new D.Activity()
    {
        ActivityType = activityType,
        ActivityTypeID = activityType.ActivityTypeID,
        ClientID = this.Client.ClientID,
        Description = model.ActivityDescription,
        PerformedByEmployeeID = this.User.UserId,
        PerformedDate = model.WorkDay,
        ProjectID = model.EntityID,
        StartTime = model.ActivityStartTime,
        StopTime = model.ActivityStopTime
    };

    activities.Add(activity);
    Session["Activities"] = activities;
}
```

This is how I save the Activity entities:

```
using (var dbContext = new D.DataClassesDataContext())
{
    var activities = (Session["Activities"] as List<D.Activity>);
    dbContext.Activities.InsertAllOnSubmit(activities);
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here: when you load entities EntityFramework tracks the changes for you.
You change your entities and then write them into the session, which creates a new object and not a reference to your loaded entities.
Then you load that object again and cast it as a List. Now you insert the session list and EF still kept track of the changes on the loaded entities and saves those aswell as the duplicated list.

In short: Get rid of the session stuff, because it's not a reference to your list, but a copy of it. It's unnecessary too, if you design your application properly.

Comment: Correction after reading your question properly: The loaded ActivityTypes are copied when you write your list to the session and thus duplicated. EF treats them as new Entities and inserts new records then.